# How to get nearby stations and next departures from google maps transit api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can I make a queries to the transit part of the google maps API that

1. For a given GPS coordinate, give me nearby stations?
2. For a given stations, give me the next departures?

Google maps itself provides that information (see screenshot). But is this information accessible through the API? [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everything that the Google Maps app can do are readily available in the Google Maps Javascript API / Web services. So don't expect to be able to copy the Google Maps app features.

You can easily get `transit_stations` by using a Places Nearby Search.
See docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

But you can only get departure times of a transit stop in the context of a Directions query. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitInformation